# which access permissions required by co-administrator to see azure active directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

administrator user added in our azure subscription and when this user logins to azure portal and trying to access azure active directory it showing there is no access to it.

my question is : which access permissions required by co-administrator to see azure active directory

Answer (score 1):

So basically depending on your needs you need to assign different permission to the user. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-assign-admin-roles) is the list of roles and their description, and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-users-assign-role-azure-portal) is the guide to assign them using the portal

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior is different depends on you are attempting to login the Classic Azure Portal (https://manage.windowsazure.com) or the New Azure Portal (https://portal.azure.com).

**Classic Azure Portal:**

Non-administrator Users cannot have any access to the Azure AD until you assign them a correct **directory role** (Global Admin for example).
[image]

**New Azure Portal:**

By default, users can see and access the Azure AD node, they can also see the other users/groups in this node although they don't have any permission to modify these resources, no matter if they have be assigned a directory role or not. You can also block the non-administrator's access to this node by configuring the "**Administration Portal**" option in the "**User Settings**" tab.

[image]